# How to get unique list of values from the list of dictonaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary, unique

I have a python list of dictionaries like this

```py
test_list = [{'id': 0, 'A':True, 'B':123},
             {'id':76, 'A':True, 'B':73},
             {'id':5, 'A':False, 'B':223},
             {'id':5, 'A':False, 'B':223},
             {'id':85, 'A':True, 'B':4},
             {'id':81, 'A':False, 'B':76},
             {'id':76, 'A':True, 'B':73}]
```

And I want to make this list unique
using simple `set(test_list)` give you `TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'`

#### My below answer works fine for me, but I am looking for a better and short answer

```py
unique_ids = list(set([x['id'] for x in test_list]))
d = {}
for item in test_list:
    d[item['id']] = item

new_d = []
for x in unique_ids:
    new_d.append(d[x])
```

Comment: Since your code works, It seems to me this question is more suited to be asked in the  [Code Review Forum](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).  Code Review is a question and answer site for peer programmer code reviews. Please read the relevant guidance related to how to properly ask questions on this site before posting your question.

Comment: `list({ d["id"] : d for d in test_list}.values())`

Answer (score 1):

Create a new dictionary with keys as ids and the values as the entire dictionary and access only the `values`:

```
new_d = list({v["id"]: v for v in test_list}.values())

>>> new_d
[{'id': 0, 'A': True, 'B': 123},
 {'id': 76, 'A': True, 'B': 73},
 {'id': 5, 'A': False, 'B': 223},
 {'id': 85, 'A': True, 'B': 4},
 {'id': 81, 'A': False, 'B': 76}]
~~
```